# Simple Spring Oauth2 flow using Postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, postman

hello i'm a beginner with Oauth2 flow.
I'm working with a simple example :
[Github Project here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/tests/annotation/vanilla)
but i failed at making a proper connection.
I have received an error message like : "couldn't complete Oauth 2.0 login "

I filled the Request Token popup with the values below :

> Callback URL : getpostman.com/oauth2/callback
>
> Token Name : mytoken
>
> Auth URL : localhost:8080/admin/oauth
>
> Acces Token URL : localhost:8080/admin/oauth/token
>
> ClientID : my-client-with-secret
>
> Client Secret : secret
>
> Grant Type : Authorization Code

Whats wrong with the information i provided ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few incorrect things that I've noticed.

1. Auth URL value should be  localhost:8080/admin/oauth/authorize
2. As "Grant Type" you've set "Authorization Code" in your request, but at the server side for that user (ClientID : my-client-with-secret /Client Secret : secret) the allowed grant types are "client_credentials" and "password".

Although this post is a few months old and probably you've solved your problem , it may help someone with similar problem like yours.